# jq: print "-" for objects which don't have a specific key

Tags: jq

I have following json:

```
[
  {
    "user": "u1",
    "id": "0001"
  },
  {
    "user": "u2",
    "id": "0002",
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": "100001",
        "name": "G1"
      },
      {
        "id": "100002",
        "name": "G2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "user": "u3",
    "id": "0003",
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": "100001",
        "name": "G1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected output is:

```
u1      0001    -
u2      0002    G1,G2
u3      0003    G1
```

I have following jq command:

```
jq -r 'map(select(.groups[].id)?)| map([.user, .id, ([.groups[].name]|join(","))] | join("\t")) | join("\n")' json
```

which produces:

```
u2      0002    G1,G2
u2      0002    G1,G2
u3      0003    G1
```

How to have on output also objects having no of the *groups* keys and avoid duplicates as showed above?

Comment: You have a typo in your expected output, the first row is supposed to be `u1      0001    -`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `jq` should give you the desired result -

```
jq -r 'def groups(d): if d | length > 0 then d | map(.name) | join(",") else "-" end; map("\(.user)     \(.id)     \(groups(.groups))") | .[]'
```

```
u1     0001     -
u2     0002     G1,G2
u3     0003     G1
```

Comment: Instead of string interpolation, `map([.user, .id, groups(.groups)])[] | @tsv` is concise